# Appending values to mainform with values selected from Modal form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, jquery

I have a view where I have the user select a email address from a modal form and update the value in the text box in the main form

```
   <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.Label("Additional Email Address") %>           
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field modADLookup">          
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor_Readonly(model => model.AdditionalEmailsSentTo, new {@class = "adEmail", style = "width:500px; height:40px;" })%>
        <%: Html.SecurityTrimmedActionButton(true, "Search Active Directory", "Index", "ActiveDirectory", null, "clsSearchButton")%>
    </div>
```

Suppose I select the email abc@abc.com, the text box loads with the value "abc@abc.com", now when I select xyz@xyz.com the next time, it replaces the "abc@abc.com" with "xyz@xyz.com".

What I'm looking for is a way to append the email address and have the text box retain the existing email id's.

For example: after the 2nd selection it should have "abc@abc.com, xyz@xyz.com".

How do I do the appending in the main form?

Thanks
Sue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After selecting the correct value, catch the value via jquery and append it to the AdditionalEmailsSentTo textbox.

For example when you select an email you do the following:

```
$("#SelectListThatContainsValues").change(function() {
    var newvalue = $(this).val();
    var currentValue = $("#AdditionalEmailsSentTo").val();
    $("#AdditionalEmailsSentTo").val(currentValue + "," + newValue);
});
```